# Stored Procedure Return Type Can Not Be Detected

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to drag this procedure over to the dbml in VS 2012 and I am getting the return type cannot be detected message.

I have tried these:
[LINQ to SQL - Stored Procedure Return Type Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226375/linq-to-sql-stored-procedure-return-type-error)
[The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035669/the-return-types-for-the-following-stored-procedures-could-not-be-detected)

I tried re-writing the procedure as a CTE and also as union to remove the OR, but it is giving me the same message.

The only return type in the designer properties for the method is int32.

Here is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStringFromFiles]
    @SearchWord NVARCHAR(100) = null
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @SearchWord = UPPER(@SearchWord);

Select    
       a.FileId     <---Guid
     , a.FileData   <---Binary
     , a.BaselineId <---Guid
     , a.FileName   <---NVARCHAR
     , a.FileExtension  <---NVARCHAR
     , b.FileByItemId   <----Guid
     , b.ItemId   <---Guid
From FileTable a

    Inner Join

     FileByItem b on a.FileId = b.FileId 

     WHERE CONTAINS(a.FileData,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, @SearchWord)') or FREETEXT(a.FileData, @SearchWord)
    RETURN 1
END
```

**UPDATE:**

A.  I can add it if I comment out the entire Where Clause -- Auto-Generated-ReturnType

B.  If I take away the or and just use:

`WHERE CONTAINS(a.FileData,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, @SearchWord)')`

it lets me add it -- Auto-Generated-ReturnType

C. If I just use

`WHERE FREETEXT(a.FileData, @SearchWord)`

It throws the error so it doesnt like the FREETEXT

If I comment the where clause out and add it and let it generate the return type then alter the procedure in the db are there any issues with that?

Comment: Can't you just remove that extra `RETURN` at the end?

Comment: it maybe where the return is, move it to the right of WHERE and see if that helps.

Comment: I updated my question. It doesnt like FREETEXT for some reason

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish by adding the `RETURN`? My advice would be to either omit it completely or explicitly return a value (i.e. `RETURN 1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
RETURN 1
```

is the culprit in both the cases. Lose it and Linq should be able to detect the types your result set.

> Linq to Sql won't get the results directly from a Stored procedure.
>   Instead an ISingleResult will be returned. You have to enumerate
>   through the result set to get the values returned from the stored
>   procedure

Comment: try to use simply return

Comment: Tried that already as well!  It will take WHERE CONTAINS(a.FileData,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, @SearchWord)')  and auto resolve the return type.  It is the FREETEXT() that it does not like.

Comment: Found this link!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965211/how-to-retrieve-multiple-rows-from-a-stored-procedure-with-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat related.  I stumbled across the same error today but for a different reason.  If your query uses a temporary table in its results then it is unable to automatically assign the return type.

I changed it to a table variable (performance was not a major concern/and was not impacted)

Hope this helps someone browsing.

Answer (score 0):

If the stored procedure have any error also then this error can occur, for me its happened once since one of the table name was changed.

Another factor is to set Primary Keys and table relations if possible

Answer (score 0):

**A simple way to solve this issue is (December 2019)**

- Just making double # precede #tmp => ##tmp
- Comment out DROP TABLE #tmp => --DROP TABLE #tmp
- Execute stored procedure
- Drag stored procedure again and That's it, It will generate return type
- Last, Turn your store back to the first situation and then save.

Hope I can help.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to drag this procedure over to the dbml in VS 2019 and I am getting this error - Stored Procedure Return Type Error The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected.

I tried rewriting the Stored procedure but nothing goes well.
Later I found that the table from where I created the Stored procedure will added some information like abc.tblname where abc is the name of the username. Like in the example below.

**Problem**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [abc].[tb_mobile](..
```

**Solution**:

I just Converted this to dbo.

```sql
Example - `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_mobile]( ..
```

Now all my Stored procedure and the issue which I faced is totally resolved.

Hope this will work for you.